# Returning cast members with odata netflix query

Tags: odata, netflix

I am trying to get the list of cast members in a movie when I request titles by genre and ratings.

I use: 
   dim catalogitem = 
        (For g in Genre 
         For t in g.titles 
         Where t.genre = "Westerns" 
         Where t.rating >=4 
         select t).Take(100)

This works great, but I also want the cast members of these movies.  How do I change this query to include returning the cast members also?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can expand cast using the OData URI:

```
http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$filter=Name%20eq%20'The%20Name%20of%20The%20Rose'&$expand=Cast&$format=json
```

From this page:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/16/fun-with-odata-and-windows-phone-7.aspx

It looks like what you need to do is define the expand when you're defining the URL for the request:

```
Dim url = String.Format("/Genres('{0}')?$expand=Titles", Me.textBox1.Text)
Dim uri = New Uri(url, UriKind.Relative)
```

So for your case:
    Dim url = String.Format("/Genres('{0}')?$expand=Cast", Me.textBox1.Text)

Note that you'll also need to change your query to ask for the Cast:

```
from t in Titles select new {t, t.Cast}
```